# Como realizar restore de apenas 1 tabela específica no SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Boa tarde!

Galera, estou com uma seguinte situação: Tenho um backup da base de dados e no servidor já foi criado um banco com esse base chamada teste, porém, preciso migrar uma tabela específica que está nessa base teste para outra base de dados chamada Producao que consta no mesmo servidor. O nome da tabela é complemento.

Comment: Ola, acho que o link abaixo vai resolver 
[https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate-restore-single-table-azure-backup]

Comment: cade o link @RenanSilveira?

Comment: Não Esta Visível ? 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate-restore-single-table-azure-backup

Comment: Isso não é só para o SQL Azure?

Comment: Mal eu li apenas o texto agora vi que é SQL server 2012

Comment: Verifica se esse Ajuda, se não apago os comentários, para o post não ficar muito sujo.
https://www.tiagoneves.net/blog/restaurar-uma-database-sql-server-2012-em-uma-instancia-sql-server-inferior/

Comment: amigo, ta dando o erro quando chega na ultima janela q é na validação: Messages
Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "CompColID".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - ComplementoColunas" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: @RenanBessa: Se o objetivo é migrar o conteúdo de uma tabela de um banco para outro, ambas no mesmo computador, me parece mais confiável e simples que rode, no banco de dados de produção, programa de importação do conteúdo da tabela.

Comment: Deu certo mestre. obg @JoséDiz

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um insert de um banco para o outro, criando a tabela no banco produção neste processo.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Producao]..SysObjects WHERE Name LIKE 'complemento')                 
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO [Producao].dbo.[complemento] FROM [teste].dbo.[complemento]
END
```